# Multiprocessing for appending text extracted with a loop to a list in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

As a Python (and programming) novice, I am trying to extract the text of thousands of PDFs into a file (or list, if better). The data is going to be used for content analysis at a later stage. I created a working function that iterates through all PDFs in a directory, extracts text using `pdfplumber` and appends it to a list.

I would now like to use multiprocessing in order to speed up what otherwise would be a horrendously lengthy process. However, I can't seem to figure out how to best implement a loop that appends to a list using parallel processes. Below is an attempt to use code from some tutorials using `concurrent.futures` with my function:

```
import pdfplumber
import os
import concurrent.futures

def pdfextractor(file):
    text = []
    for file in os.listdir("./processing/"):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            with pdfplumber.open("./processing/" + file) as pdf:
                pdf_page = pdf.pages[0]
                single_page_text = pdf_page.extract_text()
                text.append(str(single_page_text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
    futures = [executor.submit(pdfextractor, 'file')]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

This results in several processes being started appending the same PDF text to the `text` list. Changing `ProcessPoolExecutor` to `ThreadPoolExecutor` yields the desired output of the function but no increase in speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering, I managed to figure this out. Here is the code which reduced the required time to run the function by more than half. I split my function in two to better fit  `concurrent.futures`. `extract_pdf` goes through all pages of a PDF, extracts the text and appends it to a list. `extract_all` then iterates this process over an entire directory. The result is a nested list.

```
def extract_pdf(filename, directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(filename)
    allpages_text = []
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        with pdfplumber.open(directory + filename) as pdf:
            for page in pdf.pages:
                text = page.extract_text()
                allpages_text.append(text)
            allpages_text = '-'.join(allpages_text)
            return allpages_text


def extract_all(directory):
    data = []

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:

        futures = {executor.submit(extract_pdf, filename, directory): filename for filename in os.listdir(directory)}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            try:
                result = future.result()
                data.append(result)
            except Exception as exc:
                print("There was an error. {}".format(exc))
    return data



if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = './test/'

    results = extract_all(directory)
```

This website was very helpful for me to better understand what was going on with the `concurrent.futures` module: https://rednafi.github.io/digressions/python/2020/04/21/python-concurrent-futures.html